# Rebasing after a Pull request

Tags: git, github, git-rebase, git-pull, pull-request

I have a feature branch `test`. I made my changes and committed my changes to that branch. Meanwhile my `master` tip was changed (Assume it had more commits from other developers).

Before pushing my changes to my remote branch, I did a `git rebase` and then pushed my changes and created a Pull Request.

For my pull request, there were a few comments which I need to fix them.

After fixing, I saw that my `master` branch was updated. (Assume some more commits from other developers).

At any point, the reason to merge `master` onto `test` branch is that : there might be scenarios where the changes in master needs to be integrated and test the application with this feature branch

In this situation, I have 2 questions.

1. How can I merge/rebase the new changes of `master` onto my `test` branch without having a merge commit in my `test` branch? This way I will have both my previous commits which are a part of Pull Request and the new commit which is a Pull Request comment fixes.
2. How can I merge/rebase `master` onto `test` and add the new commit to my existing previous commit so that I always will have a single commit in my PR?

Comment: Are you using rebase for any specific reason instead of merge? Why checkout to `test` and run `git merge master`?

Comment: Rebase to avoid nee merge commits

Comment: Okay, Instead, you should consider using `merge --ff` instead if that's the only reason.

Comment: Your second question is somewhat unclear to me. If it is not just a rephrasing of your first question, then please note that when asking questions on Stack Overflow, you should [limit yourself to one question per post](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts).

Comment: @ScottWeldon : My second question is that, after a PR if I fix those PR comments, instead of committing a new commit, I want to rebase `test` branch with `master` and then append the new commits to my earlier commit. This way PR will have a single commit

Answer (score 14):

First of all, determine if you actually need the new changes from `master` to be integrated into your feature branch. It may be that you can ignore the new changes from `master`. If they don't conflict with your changes in `test`, then this is the easiest thing to do, and the maintainer will be able to merge your PR anyway.

You can easily see if this is the case by checking the GitHub PR page. If you get an "unable to automatically merge" message, you'll have to use one of the following solutions.

---

The standard way to include upstream changes without merging is to just rebase again:

```
git checkout test
git rebase master
```

Since this rewrites history, you will need to force-push:

```
git push --force-with-lease
```

Your PR will be updated with all of your commits, and will now include the new commits on `master` in its history.

Obligatory **warning**: Since a rebase rewrites history, this can be dangerous / disruptive for anyone else working on this branch. Be sure you clearly communicate what you have done with anyone you are collaborating with.

If you don't want to rebase, your other options are:

- Merge `master` into `test`, but you've stated you don't want to do this.
- `git cherry-pick` any new commits on `master`. This has the downside of duplicating those commits on your branch.
- Do a squash merge of `master` into `test`: `git merge --squash master`. This is similar in effect to `cherry-pick`, but creates only one commit.

Comment: The reason to rebase or merge not because git says `PR can be merged` There might be scenarios where the changes in master needs to be integrated and test the application with this feature branch

Comment: @Rams Ah, okay. That's a valid reason. You should probably [edit](//stackoverflow.com/help/editing) your question to mention that.